# How can I check if the numbers contains arabic numbers in a list of string

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, arabic

I have a list of strings , which may contain `english` numbers and `arabic` numbers.

What I need to do is to convert `arabic` numbers in to `english` numbers.

for which I am using the below code .

```
private string toEnglishNumber(string input)
    {
        string EnglishNumbers = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Char.IsDigit(input[i]))
            {
                EnglishNumbers += char.GetNumericValue(input, i);
            }
            else
            {
                EnglishNumbers += input[i].ToString();
            }
        }
        return EnglishNumbers;
    }
```

Now I need to make sure before passing my string in to this function that string contains the arabic numbers for example :

List of strings :

```
[
    "٠٥٥ ٥٣٠ ٨٦٨٤" , "+966557864894"
]
```

So instead of passing both string , I just need to pass only 0 index string which contains arabic numbers , how can I do it.

Comment: The first contains arabic numbers but also spaces. Is it a valid number anyway?

Comment: I have implemented a method which is converting that into valid format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method:

```
public static bool HasArabicGlyphs(string text)
{
    foreach (char glyph in text)
    {
        if (glyph >= 0x600 && glyph <= 0x6ff) return true;
        if (glyph >= 0x750 && glyph <= 0x77f) return true;
        if (glyph >= 0xfb50 && glyph <= 0xfc3f) return true;
        if (glyph >= 0xfe70 && glyph <= 0xfefc) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

```
List<string> arabicStrings = stringList.FindAll(HasArabicGlyphs);
```

Credits to Hans [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/48facc69-9506-4146-b1b9-e1f3ef4e0ce7/how-do-i-check-whether-my-string-contains-arabic-characters-or-not?forum=csharpgeneral)